# How to effectively capture GET and POST to a WinForms c# through IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, api-design

I have my own WinForms c# application and want to add some API functionality. I also have up and running Windows Server 2012 with IIS that is used for third-party application.

The problem is I can't wrap my mind what would be the most effective (= scalable, secure, manageable, powerful but simple enough) way to grab GET and POST requests in my desktop c# app (and respond to them). There're too many options range from c# web-server embedded library (simplest solution) to the newest ASP.net-based frameworks (most complex ones require too much learning).

I think it would be reasonable to avoid setup another c#-based server just to deal with HTTP requests and use the power of existing IIS instead.

Could you please advise specific library, sample code or walkthrough how to deal with HTTP requests in WinForms through IIS but without overwhelmingly complex ASP solutions?

Comment: Just use the build in HttpClient in .net to achieve that, it should support everything you need, if it doesnt, try to exten its functionality, most of the other 'complex libraries will call use the same methodology

Comment: No, HttpClient is not capable to listen http requests. HttpListener or more recent WebListener does but I'm not going to create a mess of same port listening in different apps. I want to use IIS.

Answer (score 0):

IIS only listen to http.sys so IIS application pool will only handle the request delivered from http.sys.

This link is about how IIS handle these requests
[[What is request-processing pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879944/what-is-request-processing-pipeline][1])

The special IIS pipeline decide that you can't force IIS listen to your Winform application directly.
Now that http client is not capable, may I know how did your winform application receive http request?

I think you could host an web app in IIS then proxy these request to IIS web app. You need make some code change in winform application so that IIS would help you handle the incoming GET/POST http requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I have learned so far is that .aspx HTTP handler maybe a solution.

Comment: Emmm.. so you are mention an Winform application or an web from application?

Comment: The plan is to use IIS probably along with kind of web application to capture and respond to web requests. Further operations will be handled by existing Winform application. There is no problem to make any modifications to Winform to accommodate connection between IIS and exiting app; I'm relatively fluent in C# Winform.  The question is in IIS part and "connector".

Comment: I see. If you just want to capture incoming request.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework.  IIS custom handler and module would be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with ASP.NET app with regular API controller, that is how to those things are supposed to be built. Works great. Adding API to WinForm was definitely bad idea.